# "Unable to request pty" PHP - rsync

Tags: php, rsync, pty

I want to connect via [SSH2](https://phpseclib.com/docs/commands#read-with-regular-expressions-sudo) and transfer files with `rsync` but I get the following error. What could be the reason for this?

```
$ssh = new SSH2('storage.example.com');
    if (!$ssh->login('username', 'helloWorld')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    } else {
        echo "asdas";
    }
    $ssh->exec("rsync --progress --rsh='ssh -p23' --recursive /var/.../backups hello@storage.example.com:backupsForProjects/april_2022/");
    $output = $ssh->read('#[pP]assword[^:]*:#', SSH2::READ_REGEX);
    if (preg_match('#[pP]assword[^:]*:#', $output)) {
        $ssh->write("HeLLoPaSSwoRD\n");
    }
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to request pty in /var/www/***/web/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:3000 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/***/web/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php(3118): phpseclib3\Net\SSH2->initShell() #1 /var/www/***/web/test2.php(13): phpseclib3\Net\SSH2->read() #2 /var/www/***/web/index.php(118): include('/var/www/client...') #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/***/web/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 3000
```

Comment: `rsync` needs a terminal to prompt for the password. Use the `pty` argument to `exec()`.

Comment: @Barmar I checked the [documentation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html) and found the `PTY` argument you mentioned and added it above my own code `$ssh->enablePTY();` . I got the error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function enablePTY() on null`. I think I missed a place.

Comment: That's the wrong documentation. The PHP documentation is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) and there's no `enablePTY()` method. Use the `pty` argument to `$ssh->exec()`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251942/can-anyone-explain-the-pty-argument-in-ssh2-exec-function-call

Comment: Alternatively, stop using passwords and start using SSH keys.

Comment: @Barmar Hello again, I stopped working last night because it was too late on Turkey's timezone. After some research this morning, I found the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` tag and inserted it into my `rsync` code and I learned the [sshpass](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Debian_10&p=ssh&f=6) feature. I installed the `sshpass` module on my server. The result worked. I transferred the files without any problems. Thank you for your help and guidance.